# C++ unable to create instance of an class

Tags: c++, c++11

I am not able to understand why the object creation n my below code is wrongly implemented:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class A
{
public:
    A(std::string apptype) : m_apptype(apptype)
    {
        std::cout << m_apptype << std::endl;
    }
    A(std::string&& apptype) : m_apptype(apptype)
    {
        std::cout << m_apptype << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string m_apptype;
};

int main()
{
    A(std::string("Test"));
    return 0;
}
```

I get the below error when I compile my code:

```
$ c++ Calender.cpp
Calender.cpp:10:14: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&&' token
 A(std::string&& apptype) : m_apptype(apptype)
              ^
Calender.cpp:10:1: error: 'A::A(std::string)' cannot be overloaded
 A(std::string&& apptype) : m_apptype(apptype)
 ^
Calender.cpp:6:1: error: with 'A::A(std::string)'
 A(std::string apptype) : m_apptype(apptype)
 ^
Calender.cpp: In constructor 'A::A(std::string)':
Calender.cpp:10:38: error: 'apptype' was not declared in this scope
 A(std::string&& apptype) : m_apptype(apptype)
                                      ^
```

Comment: There's no `std::map` in there. And it looks like your compiler is configured for C++03, and chokes on the rvalue reference.

Comment: Corrected the question title

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11 support enabled?

Comment: Thanks for to compile -std=c++11 option resolved the issue

Comment: Don't forget to fix your indentation. That's extremely important from a perspective of understanding intent.

Comment: Btw your move ctor is equal to copy and does not make any sense, you need to move parameter

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the ctor issue - sorry I am unable to exactly make out the issue?

Comment: It needs to be `A(std::string&& apptype) : m_apptype(std::move(apptype)) {}`, you are copying it now, not moving. And you do not actually need it, you can just move argument when you pass `std::string` by value. This ctor would make sense when first one accepts `const std::string &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate your object A the replace the follow line

```
A(std::string("Test"));
```

to

```
A a(std::string("Test"));
```

I suppose you try to move the value passed to 'a' when you create an initialize with '&&', but you can't move the temporary string created by the function string() passed as parameter, then it won't compile too. You need to create a variable as shown below:

```
std::string S("Test");
A a(S);
```

But it always will make a copy of S and what you want is an object you can copy or move the string passed to it. The solution is make a move when you pass 'S' to 'a' as demonstrated below:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(const std::string apptype) : m_apptype(apptype) {
            std::cout << m_apptype;
        }

    private:
        std::string m_apptype;
};

int main() {
    std::string S("Test");

    A a(S);
    std::cout << (S.empty()?" moved":" copied") << " from S\n";

    A b(move(S));
    std::cout << (S.empty()?" moved":" copied") << " from S\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create an object of class A
`A(std::string("Test"));` is not creating an object of class A just calling parameterized constructor of class A.

You should instead change it to `A obj(std::string("Test"));.

Second, `A(std::string&& apptype) : m_apptype(apptype)` is not correctly implemented. The member initialization is trying to assign a string reference `apptype` to string object `m_apptype` which could lead to unexpected results.

Correcting, these should get it working considering the example you have shared.